# Firebase - add database rules - Path contains invalid characters

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm following the [tutorial of firebase](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#5).
But I can´t add the rules `.read` and `.write`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Still happens the same. Why downvote??

Comment: Maybe you missunderstand the RULE tab and the DATA tab.

Comment: Have a look at image in my answer you need to select **RULES** tab which is besides DATA

Comment: @Ricardo I am facing the same issue with the tutorial.  Did you find a definitive answer to your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding rules at **wrong** place.  That is the reason for downvotes. This is the data structure not your rules document.

Put json rules under **database rules tab.** You have to put rules here. Please check. [image]

Comment: The OP's question was about **DATA** tab in Firebase DB, not **RULES** tab.

Answer (score 28):

Actually, this Firebase DB error is frequently caused by an outdated webpage cache.  All you need to do is refresh the **Realtime Database** webpage, and then you'll be able to add your new values:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the path that includes the key CANNOT have "." period marks according to [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data).

> As all Firebase Realtime Database data is stored as JSON objects, when
>   you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum
>   of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control
>   characters 0-31 or 127. You cannot use ASCII control characters in the
>   values themselves, either.

I wish this helps you.

And if you want to deal with RULES follow what [IGOR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238937/igor-ganapolsky) said.
Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

Firebase Database path can't contain some special characters like " . " , "@" etc. and above all you are adding the rule in the wrong place

Comment: Perhaps show where the rule should be added to really provide a good answer.

Comment: Both parts of your answer have already been given by other people.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should log in again in your account